# Nodejs serialport error when trying to open port

Tags: node.js, serial-port, node-serialport

Here is environment details:

package.json `"serialport": "^11.0.0"`

node -v `v18.16.0`

npm -v `9.5.1`

index.js

```
const {SerialPort} = require('serialport');

const port = new SerialPort({
    path: '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudRate: 57600,
});
```

console (with non-sudo user)

```
$ node index
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: Error: Permission denied, cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0
Emitted 'error' event on SerialPort instance at:
    at SerialPort._error (/var/www/node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/stream/dist/index.js:78:18)
    at /var/www/node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/stream/dist/index.js:111:18

Node.js v18.16.0
```

console (with sudo user):

```
$ sudo node index
/var/www/node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/stream/dist/index.js:71
        return (this.port?.isOpen ?? false) && !this.closing;
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/node-serialport/node_modules/serialport/dist/serialport-mock.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run node with elevated privileged or give your current user access to serial port.

[How do I allow a non-default user to use serial device ttyUSB0?](https://askubuntu.com/a/112572)

[Read/Write to a Serial Port Without Root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14363)

Answer (score 0):

try this, it's work for me.

step 1: npm i -g phantomjs.

step 2: make sure vue.config.js setting like below

```
pluginOptions: {
  electronBuilder: {
    externals: ['serialport'],
    ...
```

and

```
chainWebpack(config) {
  config.externals({
    serialport: 'serialport'
  });
  ...
```

step 3: run **`yarn add serialport`**, and it's done.

if your system is windows, make sure using admin user